# Active X control blocking keyboard events in Visual Basic.net

Tags: vb.net, keydown

I have the `vlc AxVLCPlugin21` control inside of a visual basic 2010 form and I have set it with the
ability to recognize to pause the video or music whenever I tap the space key.
The code below works and pauses the media when the windows form is showing and the vlc control is
not full screen. However when I make the vlc full screen and tap the space bar the media no longer
pauses. I think the full screen mode causes the windows form keydown event to be blocked.

I am not sure what I could try to fix this. I know the windows form has a previevkeydown event listed below
and the vlc control itself has its own previewkeydown event. But not sure what I might try to get the pause
to work when the space bar is pressed while in full screen mode. Any ideas appreciated. I have often had
problems getting keypresses to work with programs in VB. Is it because different controls seize control depending
on various settings?

I also use a `Me.KeyPreview = True` in the form load which supposedly forces the windows form to take precedence over taking keystrokes.

One other idea I tried but did not work was using `e.Handled = True` in the
keydown event which supposedly makes the form take all keyboard events and
will not allow other controls to receive them. Did not work in full screen.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

        If e.KeyValue = Keys.Space Then
            AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.togglePause()
        End If

End Sub



Private Sub Form1_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles MyBase.PreviewKeyDown

End Sub

Private Sub AxVLCPlugin21_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles AxVLCPlugin21.PreviewKeyDown

End Sub
```